# Dragging a file between desktops in El Capitan

Tags: macos, mission-control

Say you have 5 desktops open in Mission Control in El Capitan.
If you select a file to drag it to an app or another folder which lies in a different desktop, Mission Control always takes you to desktop 1 (far left).

Can you fix this somehow?
It was ok with all previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you have the Finder assigned to a specific Space. Right click it & see what it says in Options [as in the picture below, it will only show a specific number if it is assigned to a Space you're not currently on - otherwise will just show All/This/None]

[image]

The quickest way to carry any file to another Space is to hold it then invoke the key command for the Space you need - by default  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd> 
This also works for any Application window.

The key commands are automatically added each time you make a new Space, but are not switched on by default. System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control to enable...

[image]

Also, by default, the number keys are those above the QWERTY part of the keyboard. If you wish to use a 10-key instead, you must replace the default key combis with ones using the 10-key [this is not obvious as they both look identical but are responded to individually]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Finder under right click - options is assigned to all desk tops which means its not working! and this is quite a problem if you are used all this years to drag a file from a current desktop to an app or folder to another desktop by shortcuttting with a hot corner to mission control and dragging the file to the other space....

Comment: ah, ok - not something I've ever done, sorry. My 'move' has always been 'grab/key-command' I find going via Mission Control too many clicks, & I like Finder locked to Space 1 so I always know where it is. i guess just different 'muscle-memory' as a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,
Finder under right click - options is assigned to all desk tops which means its not working!
 and this is quite a problem if you are used all this years to drag a file from a current desktop to an app or folder to another desktop by shortcuttting with a hot corner to mission control and dragging the file to the other space....